# Difference between Row-Modelling and EAV

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, database-schema, entity-attribute-value

What is the main difference between Row Modelling and EAV (Entity-Atribute-Value)?

I think EAV is a subset of Row Modelling but I cant state the main differences.

 If possible, please use references in your answers.

Comment: Is this what you mean by [Row Modelling](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC353023/)?

Comment: Yes this is a good definition.

Comment: They seem to me to be the same thing.  What makes you believe that `Row-Modelling` is not just someone's home-grown name for EAV?

Comment: In this paper: (Dinu, V., & Nadkarni, P. (2007). Guidelines for the effective use of entity-attribute-value modeling for biomedical databases. International journal of medical informatics), they are treated as different things. But I couldnt fully understand the difference.

Comment: I've never heard of it being called Row-Modeling but am now curious. Can you post the paper somewhere?

Comment: @JoelBrown according to Wikipedia, row modelling is a restricted version of EAV ... less flexible, but more safe.

Comment: @MattFenwick - Quite right. The Wikipedia article makes a distinction, but I would say that the term _row modelling_ is not widely used and in fact what most practitioners are talking about when they talk (or _rant_) about EAV is what the wiki article describes as _row modelling_.  I don't think you see "true EAV" - as the wiki would have us understand it - in the wild.  This leads to the discussion, perhaps more suitable for EL&U, about whether a term means what a particular authority says it means, or whether it means what most people who use it mean when they say it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

According to [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#EAV_versus_row_modeling),

> The differences between row modeling and EAV are:
>
> - A row-modeled table is homogeneous in the facts that it describes: a Line Items table describes only products sold. By contrast, an EAV table contains almost any type of fact.
> - The data type of the value column/s in a row-modeled table is pre-determined by the nature of the facts it records. By contrast, in an EAV table, the conceptual data type of a value in a particular row depend on the attribute in that row.

So here's my take on that:

- row modelling

  ```
  create table line_items (
    id int primary key,
    sale_id int,
    foreign key sale_id references sale(id),
    product_name varchar(50), -- this could also be a foreign key 
    price decimal(10, 2)
  );
  ```

  - this has some type safety:  `price` can't be some junk string
  - the only things that we put in this table are line items
  - to me, this sounds just like a normal 1:many relationship (but I'm not sure so don't quote me on that)
- entity-attribute-value

  ```
  create table my_eav (
    entity_id int,
    foreign key (entity_id) references entity(id),
    attribute varchar(50),
    value varchar(50),
    primary key (entity_id, attribute)
  );
  ```

  - the values are stored as `varchar`s -- but they could be numbers, strings, times, etc.
  - all kinds of data can be stored -- shoe size, airplane weight, the number of home runs Babe Ruth hit in 1926

---

The article goes on to say:

> The circumstances where you would need to go beyond standard row-modeling to EAV are listed below:
>
> - The data types of individual attributes varies (as seen with clinical findings).
> - The categories of data are numerous, growing or fluctuating, but the number of instances (records/rows) within each category is very small. Here, with conventional modeling, the database’s entity–relationship diagram might have hundreds of tables: the tables that contain thousands/ millions of rows/instances are emphasized visually to the same extent as those with very few rows. The latter are candidates for conversion to an EAV representation.

So if you have a lot of these 1:many relationships, do you want to have 1 table for each, as row modelling requires?  Whereas EAV would allow you to combine (some or all of) those tables into 1.